# Error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'showsAsAction' in package 6

Tags: android, android-studio, android-actionbar

I want to add profil opportunity to my action bar,but if i runt it doesnt work,I change shiwsAsAction from always to never, but it also didnt work.. i get this message in grade build:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
>   C:\Android\Celtkituzes_0_1\app\src\main\res\menu\menu.xml
>   Error:(7) No resource identifier found for attribute 'showsAsAction' in package 'sgtt.celtkituzes_0_1'
>   C:\Android\Celtkituzes_0_1\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\menu\menu.xml
>   Error:(7) No resource identifier found for attribute 'showsAsAction' in package 'sgtt.celtkituzes_0_1'
>   Warning:The `android.dexOptions.incremental` property is deprecated and it has no effect on the build process.

menu xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:appname="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_profil"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_image_timer_auto.png"
        android:title="Profil"
        app:showsAsAction="never">
    </item>


</menu>
```

Comment: Q1: What are you using `appname` for? Q2: Did you include appcompat in your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. it should be `android:` not `app:`
2. should be `showAsAction` not `showsAsAction`

You have letter **s** attached to `show`

### EDIT

For your next problem: You have to put an image also into `drawabe` folder, not only in one of the `xxxhdpi`(or similar) folders.

Comment: well, your project has more than one mistakes. My suggestions above are correct, you have to follow these steps, no matter if the problem is solved. Your problem is somewhere else.....

Answer (score 1):

The error described:

> Error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'showsAsAction'

is caused because the property must be **[app:showAsAction](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html)** (not `showsAsAction`)

And the extension for the image file is not neccesary just the name:

```
 android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_image_timer_auto"
```

This must be your `menu.xml` file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:appname="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_profil"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_image_timer_auto"
        android:title="Profil"
        app:showAsAction="never">
    </item>


</menu>
```

Comment: After your advice, i get this message: Error:(410, 69) String types not allowed (at 'ic_action_image_timer_auto.png' with value '').

Comment: ok you don´t need to put the extension of the file located in /drawable folder, change to this :             android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_image_timer_auto" and be sure to have the image inside /drawable

Comment: I get the same msg : Error:(411, 69) String types not allowed (at 'ic_action_image_timer_auto' with value '').

Comment: Do you have this image ic_action_image_timer_auto.png  inside your folder /drawable

Comment: I cant see the content of your /drawable folder in the image.

Comment: You can see in this screenshoot http://1.1m.yt/D2-7RMg.png  , i really dont know why doesnt work this..

Comment: you have to put also a default image into `drawable`folder, not only intoxxx hdpi

Comment: @Storg like Opiatefuchs  say ou have to put also a default image into drawablefolder.